Debug Flask Visual Studio Code, module started twice
I am trying to debug a small python server using Flask. I have tried many different permutations of launch.json. What happens is that the main module is started and then in a subprocess running ms-python.debugpy main.py the process is started a second time. The server spawns a thread which has a websocket server. When the second process starts, there is a fault because the socket is already bound by the first process. The debugger has attached itself to the second process and when I kill the process because of the fault it leaves the first one running but it cannot be debugged. Until the second process starts the debugger works on the first one. How can I configure launch.json to not start the subprocess. I also have to stop both instances, ie click the red box twice to stop debugging.
I have tried many variations of launch.json. How do I just start it once and use the debugger.

After I posted, I figured out I needed to set the use_reloader=False in the run command. Now it works.

Hi PJT, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also can I answer my own question..
, Just a reminder :)
